# De/serializing an enumerator type with Jackson

Tags: jersey, jackson

I have an entity I am serializing into JSON and also deserailizing from JSON:

```
public class Item {
    @JsonProperty private Status status;

....

}
```

The Status enumeration looks like:

```
public enum Status {

    NEW,
    ACTIVE,
    PENDING,
    ERROR;
}
```

I want the annotated enumeration type to serialize to, for example, {status: "NEW"} and the same to deserialize into the enumeration type.  Is there a separate annotation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some additional methods in your enum:

```
@Override
@JsonValue
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString().toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
}

@JsonCreator
public static Status fromString(final String status)
{
  if (status == null)
  {
    return null;
  }
  try
  {
    return valueOf(status.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
  }
  catch (IllegalArgumentException iae)
  {
    System.err.println("Invalid status");
  }
}
```

These also ensure that your status conversion is case-insensitive (so a status of 'new' would still convert to the correct enum).